# The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0" has not been registered

Tags: sql

This is my sql query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0',
'Excel 13.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\xxxx\sample.xlsx',
 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```

When I execute this query, I get this error :

> (The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0" has not been registered.)

Comment: can you specify what environment are you using, you may have to download this extension https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d) or MS Office 2010.
Make sure you select correct platform (x86 vs x64).

Comment: I've also got this problem and the above solution doesn't work.  I'm running 64 bit windows and 64 bit office 2016.  Code is as above, same error.  Any ideas?